# How to add <td> according to changing <th> part

Tags: php, html, mysql

My requirement is,when new version comes  in a project I need to display each test case result  in each version.

Example :-

tc_id     testcase       version1     version2  ......
1       Invalid login      pass         fail
2          .                .
3

I want to make my table as dynamic.That means when new version comes in the project column has to add.In heading part it is adding the new versions.In particular version I need to display the test case result. I am able to display by putting  but how to add  in  part according to newly added (version) means how to add  dynamically.

My code is,

```
<?php

function project_table(){
      echo '<DOCTYPE html>
             <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Dashboard/css/table_css.css">
             </head>
            <section>
             <body>';
                include("C:\wamp64\www\DashBoard\Config2.php");
                  $sql = "select version_number from version where rel_id= 1";
                  $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                 echo'<div class="tbl-header">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th colspan=4>Test case id</th>
                      <th colspan=5>Test case description</th>';
                      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                      {
                        echo'<th colspan=4>'.$row['version_number'].'</th>';
                      }
              echo'</tr>   
              </thead>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="tbl-content">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
             $sql="select prefix , tc_id ,tc_description from (select testcases.tc_id as tc_id, project_table.prefix as prefix,testcases.tc_summary as tc_description from project_table join testcases on project_table.project_id=testcases.pro_id join executions on testcases.id=executions.parent_id where executions.version_id=1 and executions.pro_id=4)as t;";
             $query=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
               echo '<tr>

                <td colspan=4>'.$row['prefix'].'</td>
                <td colspan=5>'.$row['tc_description'].'</td>
                <td colspan=5>'.$row['prefix'].'-'.$row['tc_id'].'</td>
                </tr>';

              }
            echo' 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section> 
</html>';
}

    project_table();

?>
```

And these query gives me result, this result I need to print in below the each version.

```
$res="select result from (select executions.tc_result as result from project_table join testcases on project_table.project_id=testcases.pro_id join executions on testcases.id=executions.parent_id where executions.version_id=1 and executions.pro_id=4)as t;";
```

gives means result;
can Any one help me, I am struggling a lot in that.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show some example rows of data from your database table, and an example of what the HTML table you want to produce would look like for that data?

Comment: any error comes?

Comment: change your variable names `$row` do not use same variables in different queries as it might be creates problem.